# Does PivotViewer work on localhost?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, pivotviewer

From the FAQ:

http://forums.silverlight.net/p/189106/434909.aspx/1?PivotViewer+FAQ

> Q: Why won’t my collection load in the PivotViewer control?
>
> A:
>
> 1. Is your collection hosted on a web-server?  This is required. Local collections are not supported.

Does this mean that running the pivotviewer as an app on IIS as localhost, with the collection hosted on the localhost, the control will not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work on localhost.  The current PivotViewer requires an actual http uri location to work.  So that FAQ is really just letting you know that you can't pass a file location or something like that into it.  As long as its a valid location you should be good to go.

I run all of my PV projects off of localhost while they are being developed and have never had any issues.

Comment: Thanks, Tony. That helps narrow the troubleshooting :)